# Blur filter not working on image in createGraphics image... says: Cannot read property 'getContext'

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing, p5.js

I have a main canvas where i have text..

I want to add a drop shadow to this text... So i created a createGraphics image.. where i paint the same text

In this new createGraphics image i want to add a blur.. and then copy this blured image to my main canvas....

But when i try to apply the blur.. i get this error: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined

In this sketch in line 75..(I have simplified so its easier to debug) if you uncomment thte line where i add the blur.. it get the error.. : https://codepen.io/giorgiomartini/pen/LzQeGQ?editors=0010

This is how the code looks:

```
function setup(){
  colorMode(HSB, 360) 
  createCanvas(canvasX,canvasY)
  textShadow = createGraphics(canvasX, canvasY)
}


function mouseClicked(){
    wordsUppercase = textArray.map(function(x){ return x.toUpperCase()})
    const someWord = returnRandomFromArray(wordsUppercase)

    blendMode(BLEND)
    const colsArray = randomColor({luminosity: 'light', format: 'hsl',count: 5}) 
    background(colsArray[0])
    translate(width/2, height/2)

    drawTextShadow(someWord)
    image(textShadow, -width/2,-height/2);



}

function drawTextShadow(someWord) {
  textShadow.clear()
  textShadow.translate(width/2,height/2) 


  textShadow.textSize(60)
  textShadow.fill(0)
  textShadow.textAlign(CENTER)
  textShadow.rectMode(CENTER)
  textShadow.textFont('Passion One')
  textShadow.strokeWeight(10)
  textShadow.text(someWord, 0,canvasY/2.3,canvasX/1.5,canvasY)




  textShadow.translate(-width/2,-height/2) 
  //textShadow.filter(BLUR,3)
}
```

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Seeing as you haven't included the code that actually creates the canvas object, where `getContext` is called on something that is undefined, who knows ?

Comment: have you seen the codepen? im honeslty asking... thanks :)

Comment: @adeneo Please note that this is a [tag:p5.js] question, and the `createCanvas()` function comes from the P5.js library.

Comment: @KevinWorkman do you have any idea why i get that error when i use the filter function?Thansk